# Tools to generate reportanalytics feeds from google

Tags: pdf-generation, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Can you recommend any programmable tools/extensions that can be used to generate reports out of google analytics feed on th fly? Essentially some kind of pdf generator from feed, not sure though.
Or does the Google analytics itself gives reports output as feed etc.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how technical you want to be.  The GA Data Export API can give you XML data to play with:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html

Or you could go for a higher level excel solution instead:

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/08/analytics-data-in-excel-through-our-api.html